# An optimized implementation of the Heaviside function

Tags: optimization, assembly, fortran, intel, fortran2003

I'm would like to (super)optimize an implementation of the Heaviside function.

I'm working on a numerical algorithm (in Fortran) where speed is particularly important. This employs the Heaviside function many times, currently implemented by the signum intrinsic function as follows:

```
heaviside = 0.5*sign(1,x)+1
```

I'm mainly interested in the case where x is a double precision real number on intel processors.

Is it possible to develop a more efficient implementation of the Heaviside function? 
Perhaps using assembly language, a superoptimizing code or call to an existing external library?

Comment: Check the sign bit, assuming IEEE754 floats and ignoring negative zeros?

Comment: Well `sign(0.5,x)+1` might save you a multiplication, the compiler might not optimise that out anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, strangely sign(0.5,x)+1 is slower using an optimized Intel compiler. Fortran bit testing operations to identify the sign bit are also slow. Is assuming a sign bit reasonable on modern computers? If it is, I could look into coding this check at the assembly level to maximize efficiency.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you intend `heaviside = 0.5*(sign(1,x)+1)`? In any case testing with gcc 4.8.1 fortran shows High Performance Mark's idea should be beneficial. Here are 3 possibilities:

heaviside1 - original
heaviside2 - High Performance Mark's idea
heaviside3 - another variation

```
  function heaviside1 (x)
  double precision heaviside1, x
  heaviside1 = 0.5 * (sign(1d0,x) + 1)
  end

  function heaviside2 (x)
  double precision heaviside2, x
  heaviside2 = sign(0.5d0,x) + 0.5
  end

  function heaviside3 (x)
  double precision heaviside3, x
  heaviside3 = 0
  if (x .ge. 0) heaviside3 = 1
  end

  program demo
  double precision heaviside1, heaviside2, heaviside3, x, a, b, c

  do
     x = 0.5 - RAND(0)
     a = heaviside1(x)
     b = heaviside2(x)
     c = heaviside3(x)
     print *, "x=", x, "heaviside(x)=", a, b, c
  enddo
  end
```

When compiled, gcc generates these 3 stand-alone functions:

```
<heaviside1_>:
  vmovsd    xmm0,QWORD PTR [rcx]
  vandpd    xmm0,xmm0,XMMWORD PTR [rip+0x2d824]
  vorpd     xmm0,xmm0,XMMWORD PTR [rip+0x2d80c]
  vaddsd    xmm0,xmm0,QWORD PTR [rip+0x2d7f4]
  vmulsd    xmm0,xmm0,QWORD PTR [rip+0x2d81c]
  ret    

<heaviside2_>:
  vmovsd    xmm0,QWORD PTR [rcx]
  vandpd    xmm0,xmm0,XMMWORD PTR [rip+0x2d844]
  vorpd     xmm0,xmm0,XMMWORD PTR [rip+0x2d85c]
  vaddsd    xmm0,xmm0,QWORD PTR [rip+0x2d844]
  ret    

<heaviside3_>:
  vxorpd    xmm0,xmm0,xmm0
  vmovsd    xmm1,QWORD PTR [rip+0x2d844]
  vcmplesd  xmm0,xmm0,QWORD PTR [rcx]
  vandpd    xmm0,xmm1,xmm0
  ret
```

When compiled with gcc, heaviside1 generates a multiply that might slow execution.
heaviside2 eliminates the multiply.
heaviside3 has the same number of instructions as heaviside2, but uses 2 fewer memory accesses.

For the stand-alone functions:

```
             instruction   memory reference
             count         count
heaviside1   6             5
heaviside2   5             4
heaviside3   5             2
```

The inline code for these functions avoids the need for the return instruction and ideally passes the arguments in registers and preloads other registers with needed constants. The exact result depends on the compiler used and the calling code. An estimate for inlined code:

```
             instruction   memory reference
             count         count
heaviside1   4             0
heaviside2   3             0
heaviside3   2             0
```

It looks like the function could be handled by as few as two compiler generated instructions: vcmplesd+vandpd. The first instruction creates a mask of all zeros if the argument is negative, or a mask of all ones otherwise. The second instruction applies the mask to a register constant value of one in order to produce the result value of zero or one.

Though I have not benchmarked these functions, it looks like the heaviside function should not take much execution time.

---09/23/2013: adding x86_64 assembly language versions and C language benchmark---

file functions.s

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
.intel_syntax noprefix
.text

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// this heaviside function generates its own register constants
// double  heaviside_a1 (double arg);
.globl heaviside_a1

heaviside_a1:
   mov     rax,0x3ff0000000000000
   xorpd   xmm1,xmm1                # xmm1: constant 0.0
   cmplesd xmm1,xmm0                # xmm1: mask (all Fs or all 0s)
   movq    xmm0,rax                 # xmm0: constant 1.0
   andpd   xmm0,xmm1
   retq

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// this heaviside function uses register constants passed from caller
// double  heaviside_a2 (double arg, double const0, double const1);
.globl heaviside_a2

heaviside_a2:
   cmplesd xmm1,xmm0                # xmm1: mask (all Fs or all 0s)
   movsd   xmm0,xmm2                # xmm0: constant 1.0
   andpd   xmm0,xmm1
   retq

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

file ctest.c

```
#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// functions.s
double heaviside_a1 (double x);
double heaviside_a2 (double arg, double const0, double const1);

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

static double heaviside_c1 (double x)
    {
    double result = 0;
    if (x >= 0) result = 1;
    return result;
    }

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//  queryPerformanceCounter - similar to QueryPerformanceCounter, but returns
//                            count directly.

uint64_t queryPerformanceCounter (void)
    {
    LARGE_INTEGER int64;
    QueryPerformanceCounter (&int64);
    return int64.QuadPart;
    }

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// queryPerformanceFrequency - same as QueryPerformanceFrequency, but returns  count direcly.

uint64_t queryPerformanceFrequency (void)
    {
    LARGE_INTEGER int64;

    QueryPerformanceFrequency (&int64);
    return int64.QuadPart;
    }

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// lfsr64gpr - left shift galois type lfsr for 64-bit data, general purpose register implementation
//
static uint64_t lfsr64gpr (uint64_t data, uint64_t mask)
   {
   uint64_t carryOut = data >> 63;
   uint64_t maskOrZ = -carryOut; 
   return (data << 1) ^ (maskOrZ & mask);
   }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

int runtests (uint64_t pattern, uint64_t mask)
    {
    uint64_t startCount, elapsed, index, loops = 800000000;
    double ns;
    double total = 0;

    startCount = queryPerformanceCounter ();
    for (index = 0; index < loops; index++)
        {
        double x, result;
        pattern = lfsr64gpr (pattern, mask);
        x = (double) (int64_t) pattern;
        result = heaviside_c1 (x);
        total += result;
        }
    elapsed = queryPerformanceCounter () - startCount;
    ns = (double) elapsed / queryPerformanceFrequency () * 1000000000 / loops;
    printf ("heaviside_c1: %7.2f ns\n", ns);

    startCount = queryPerformanceCounter ();
    for (index = 0; index < loops; index++)
        {
        double x, result;
        pattern = lfsr64gpr (pattern, mask);
        x = (double) (int64_t) pattern;
        result = heaviside_a1 (x);
        //printf ("heaviside_a1 (%lf): %lf\n", x, result);
        total += result;
        }
    elapsed = queryPerformanceCounter () - startCount;
    ns = (double) elapsed / queryPerformanceFrequency () * 1000000000 / loops;
    printf ("heaviside_a1: %7.2f ns\n", ns);

    startCount = queryPerformanceCounter ();
    for (index = 0; index < loops; index++)
        {
        double x, result;
        const double const0 = 0.0;
        const double const1 = 1.0;
        pattern = lfsr64gpr (pattern, mask);
        x = (double) (int64_t) pattern;
        result = heaviside_a2 (x, const0, const1);
        //printf ("heaviside_a2 (%lf): %lf\n", x, result);
        total += result;
        }
    elapsed = queryPerformanceCounter () - startCount;
    ns = (double) elapsed / queryPerformanceFrequency () * 1000000000 / loops;
    printf ("heaviside_a2: %7.2f ns\n", ns);
    return total;
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main (void)
    {
    uint64_t mask;

    mask = 0xBEFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;

    // raise our priority to increase measurement accuracy
    SetPriorityClass (GetCurrentProcess (), REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS);

    printf ("using pseudo-random data\n");
    runtests (1, mask);
    return 0;
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`mingw64 build command: gcc -Wall -Wextra -O3 -octest.exe ctest.c functions.s`

Program output from Intel Core i7-2600K at 4.0 GHz:

```
using pseudo-random data
heaviside_c1:    2.24 ns
heaviside_a1:    2.00 ns
heaviside_a2:    2.00 ns
```

These timing results include execution of pseudo-random argument generation and result totalization code needed to keep the optimizer from eliminating the otherwise unused heaviside_c1 local function.

heaviside_c1 is from the original fortran suggestion, ported to C.
heaviside_a1 is an assembly language implementation.
heaviside_a2 is a modification of the assembly language version that uses register constants passed by the caller to avoid the overhead of generating them. For my processor, benchmarking shows no advantage to passing constants.

The assembly language functions assume xmm0 returns the result and xmm1 and xmm2 are available as scratch registers. This is valid for the x64 calling convention used by Windows. This assumption should be confirmed for other calling conventions.

In order to avoid memory accesses, the assembly language version expects the argument to be passed by value in a register (XMM0). Because this is not the fortran default, a special declaration is required. This one seems to work properly for gfortran 64-bit:

```
  interface
  real(c_double) function heaviside_a1(x)
  use iso_c_binding, only: c_double
  real(c_double), VALUE :: x
  end function heaviside_a1
  end interface
```

Comment: ,thanks for the detailed response -- after looking at my ifort optimized assembly code, I'm not convinced the functions are implemented to anything like two operations (typically 6). I've benchmarked your three cases using ifort and gfortran.  ifort: H1=25.166176; H2=24.070339; H3=24.727245; gfortran: H1=28.467665; H2=28.508667; H3=28.370693. It appears there is some scope for improvement. I'm trying to implement the suggested "cmpsd" + "andpd" using intel -S and replacing, although my assembly language is pretty rusty and the intel x86_64 assembly documentation is vast and unclear.

Comment: Hello, I added an asm version and a C language benchmarking wrapper (I am more familiar with C code). The asm functions give good results (2.00 ns including pseudo-random argument generation).

Comment: Amazing, thank you @ScottD! For my timing tests using fully optimized ifort on linux I compared heaviside_c1 = 23.737394; heaviside_a1=16.656475; heaviside_a2=16.74144 and, for reference, no function call at all = 8.664681.
Note, for intel fortran, there is a required change to the interface above with the addition of the line _italic_!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES STDCALL :: heaviside_a1 (see [link](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/2011Update/fortran/lin/bldaps_for/win/bldaps_fortmasmov.htm)).

Comment: @user2776145, good to hear you are getting some performance gain. Thank you very much for the tip on calling this asm code from the Intel fortran compiler.